# Docker container update fails on Windows Server 2016

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

I have docker installed on Windows Server 2016. Basically it is AWS AMI (Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Base with Containers - ami-ffa3da90) with docker pre-installed.
When I try to update docker container using command:
`docker update --cpu-shares 512 695fee5945d0` it fails with error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot update container 695fee5945d0bf293fdfa1e9ebc6db6c0b25f221452e9c542f83af8e51ae2e28: Resource updating isn't supported on Windows
```

Is it the limitation of with Docker itself or do I need to do some configurations specific to windows.

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.2-ee-5
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   fa09039
 Built:        Wed Jul 19 23:56:45 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.2-ee-5
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   fa09039
 Built:        Wed Jul 19 23:56:45 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. Error specifically says that you can not update resources on WIndows containers, only available when you create container.

Comment: Your Docker version is way out of date. The current version is 17.06, 1.12.2 dates back to a year ago.

Comment: @ManoMarks, I updated Docker version (see updated question), still getting same error.

Comment: I checked, `docker update` is currently not supported on windows containers.

Comment: Thanks @ManoMarks for verification. I will be of great help if you can share link stating above limitations.

Comment: I work at Docker. I confirmed it internally. It should be in the `docker update` reference soon.

Comment: I think the error also states it pretty clearly: "Resource updating isn't supported on Windows"